# Inject mocks to Abstract class using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, ejb, mockito

I am mocking an abstract class like below:

`myAbstractClass = Mockito.mock(MyAbstractClass.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);`

the problem is that `MyAbstractClass` has some dependencies injected via `EJB` annotations and there are not setters. Is there a way to inject the dependencies?

`@InjectMocks` does not work with Abstract classes.

Answer (score 5):

I am using junit5 for this.

What I did is instantiate the abstract class with a `new abstractClass()` in `@BeforeEach`  and call the methods by `super` if the method is not abstract(using this because I have `protected` methods), after this I use `ReflectionUtils.setField()` to set the mocks in the abstract class and test every method and works pretty well. I leave a simple example that works.

AbstractClass

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;

  protected String getProperty(String property){
    return environment.getRequiredProperty(property);
  }
}
```

AbstractClassTest

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class AbstractClassTest {

  AbstractClass abstractClass;

  @Mock
  Environment environment;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    abstractClass = new AbstractClass() {
      @Override
      public String getProperty(String property) {
        return super.getProperty(property);
      }
    };
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(abstractClass, "environment", environment);
  }

  @Test
  void shouldReturnProperty() {
    String propertyValue = "this property";
    when(environment.getRequiredProperty("property")).thenReturn(propertyValue);
    String property = abstractClass.getProperty("property");
    assertEquals(propertyValue, property);
  }
}
```

This is just using mockito and junit5 to test.
Remember to call `ReflectionUtils` after you instantiate the class with `new AbstractClass()` or the mocks won't be injected.

Any improve on this implementation is welcome :D.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot instantiate an Abstract class there is nothing to test. I would recommend that you create child class (it could be a nested class inside your test class), and then run your tests that way. Then you can use the `@Mock`, `@InjectMocks` as you would normally.

Comment: The abstract class has some implemented methods to test

Comment: If you have an implemented class which extends the Abstract class, then just use that one to test the methods from the abstract class.

Comment: @Craig If you had multiple derived classes, which one would you put the tests in, or would you need redundant tests for every class? It makes sense to look for the test in the class the methods were implemented in.

Comment: When I have a situation like this, then I'll make an Abstract test class and then for each child class create a test class that extends from the Abstract test class. In that way you test all of the common methods and the child test class will just have the test code unique to that child class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Powermock library to inject mocks in `myAbstractClass` using `Whitebox.setInternalState(myAbstractClass, mock(MockedClass.class))`;

Answer (score 0):

***Junit 4 specific solution***

**Abstract class that need to be tested**

```
@Slf4j
public abstract class AdhocNotificationEmail {

    @Autowired
    protected CustomerNotificationRepository customerNotificationRepository;

    protected abstract  Map<String, String> abstractMethod(AdhocNotificationDTO adhocNotificationDTO);

    public JSONObject concreteMethod(){
      // some stuff that needs to be tested and common to all subclasses
    }
}
```

***Test Class:***

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AdhocNotificationEmailTest{

    @Mock
    protected CustomerNotificationRepository customerNotificationRepository;

    private AdhocNotificationEmail unit;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        unit = new AdhocNotificationEmail() {
                   @Override
                   protected Map<String, String> abstractMethod(AdhocNotificationDTO notificationDTO) {
                    return null;
                   }
               };
        unit.customerNotificationRepository = customerNotificationRepository;
    }

    @Test
    public void concreteMethod_greenPath() {
        final String templateName = "NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATE";
        final AdhocNotificationDTO adhocNotificationDTOStub = getAdhocNotificationDTOStub(templateName);
        final CustomerNotification customerNotificationStub = getCustomerNotificationStub(templateName);
        when(customerNotificationRepository.findByIdAndTemplateName(id, templateName)).thenReturn(customerNotificationStub);
        final JSONObject response = unit.concreteMethod(adhocNotificationDTOStub);
        assertNotNull(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, what I like to do is to extend the abstract with an anonymous class declared in the @Before (or @BeforeEach in junit.jupiter). This way I can achieve the following:

- Don't mock the class that I want to test (like you are doing with `Mockito.mock(MyAbstractClass.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)`), since that is kind of an anti-pattern. You only want to Mock the dependencies of the class you are testing;
- You can provide Mocks for the dependencies of the abstract class, and that are called by non-abstract methods;
- You can test non-abstract methods that call abstract methods

Example:

```
class TestAbstractClass {
    @Mock
    private ServiceDependency dependency;

    private AbstractClass abstractClass;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        abstractClass= new AbstractClass (dependency) { };
    }

    @Test
    void test(){
        Mockito.when(dependency.someMethod()).thenReturn(something);
        var result = abstractclass.someNonAbstractMethod();
        // assertions
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Good practice is to write unit tests for all possible classes which inherits from this abstract class. Because in theory it is possible situation. This dependency should be mocked and you should forget about mocking dependencies of this EJB component.
Maybe some code snippets would help to clarify what you try to achieve here.

Comment: This is a bad idea as you will end up duplicating tests in the child classes. The tests for code in the abstract class should be in a dedicated Test class, otherwise you are mixing concerns.